# Core Data iCloud fetch sometimes yields no data (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, icloud, fetch

I have a problem in my test app using iCloud Core Data.  The specific problem is triggered when a partial entry in a table view is touched which triggers the full table entry to be displayed on a full screen.  Kind of standard table view stuff.

The table view cell contains an unique record ID which is passed into the detail display view.  Upon starting up the view, the view controller get uses the full record data and paints it up on the screen.

Here is the code used to do that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSString *temp_text;
    Item *fetchSelectedItem;
    NSString *updateUniqueID;
    NSArray *tempFetchedObjects;
    NSError *error;
    int stopper;

    localFindItDataController = [[FindItDataController alloc] init];

    NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Item"  inManagedObjectContext: localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext];
    [fetch setEntity:entityDescription];
    updateUniqueID = [localItem.itemUniqueID stringValue];
    [fetch setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(ANY itemUniqueID = %@)",updateUniqueID]];

    tempFetchedObjects = [localFindItDataController.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&error];
    NSLog(@"did the fetch work %@ %lu", updateUniqueID, (unsigned long)[tempFetchedObjects count]);
    if ([tempFetchedObjects count] == 0) {
        stopper = 1;}

    fetchSelectedItem = [tempFetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0];
    NSLog(@"only executes if fetch was ok");
    localItem = fetchSelectedItem;

    temp_text = localItem.itemName;
    contentsWhatBox.text = temp_text;
    temp_text = localItem.itemLocation;
    contentsWhereBox.text = temp_text;
    temp_text = localItem.itemDescription;
    contentsOtherInfoBox.text = temp_text;

    UIImage *tempImage = [UIImage imageWithData:localItem.itemPicture];
    CGImageRef imageRef = [self CGImageRotatedByAngle:[tempImage CGImage] angle:270];
    UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
    contentsImageBox.image = img;

    tapImage = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapImageGesture)];

    [contentsImageBox setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    [contentsImageBox addGestureRecognizer:tapImage];

}
```

Mostly this works just fine but occasionally the fetch comes up empty even though there definitely is data that matches the fetch predicate.  Sometimes I can tap on a table view entry, see it come up, go back and forth a few times between table view entries, go back to the original entry and the fetch fails.

I'm at a bit of a loss and any help would be welcome.  Thanks in advance.

Edit #1:

This is the object that is being fetched.  Might matter so I added it in later:

```
@interface Item : NSManagedObject {
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemLocation;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemDescription;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSData   * itemPicture;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * itemUniqueID;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * itemNumber1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * itemNumber2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemAttribute1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemAttribute2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemAttribute3;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * itemTimestamp;


@end
```

Edit #2:

I forgot to mention that the error object from the fetch is nil after the 'bad' fetch.

Edit #3:

Added a loop to check if I got a result and retry a certain number of times before quitting and that worked ok.  I'm not sure why it's going on but I suspect the image in the iCloud data might be part of the problem even though the data at this point for sure is replicated to the iOS test device(s).

Answer (score 0):

Added a loop to check if I got a result and retry a certain number of times before quitting and that worked ok. I'm not sure why it's going on but I suspect the image in the iCloud data might be part of the problem even though the data at this point for sure is replicated to the iOS test device(s).